# TFS 2015 RC2 Editor Extension missing

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I accidentally deleted a web access extension that I believe is installed by default and allows for code editing and syntax highlighting.

Now I'm unable to edit any more documents in the web interface.
I tried repairing the install but the extension did not reappear.

Can anyone tell me where that extension can be found and how to re-install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default extension is `Advanced Code Editor Extension`

There's a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7a650551-2b56-4f2a-ac53-818dbd490e1b/how-to-upload-the-advanced-code-editor-extension-in-tfs-2012-web-access) describing how to install it manually.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you so much.